Vector field which is not a gradient of a function
Let $f(x,y)=(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$ be a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$. Show that it is not a gradient of any smooth function. I wonder if there is any approach using differential forms.
Here are my thoughts: suppose for contradiction that there exists a smooth $g:\mathbb{R^2}-\{(0,0)\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=f(x,y)$. Then we may pick a well-defined volume form $dx\wedge dy$, where the cotangent vectors are induced by identity diffeomorphism with $\mathbb{R^2}$. So that multiplying this form by relation above yields a well-defined form $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dx\wedge dy+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}dx\wedge dy=f(x,y)dx\wedge dy$. Then note the left hand side is an exterior derivative $d(-gdx+gdy)$ so we may apply Stoke's theorem to conclude the integral of LHS is zero (since our space has no boundary). Then it suffices to arrive at contradiction with $\int fdxdy=0$; however, I am not seeing how to show this is not possible. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Your idea is sound, but the formalism is off. The function $f$ is a function $\mathbb{R}^2-0\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, so it would at best be the gradient of a function $g\colon\mathbb{R}^2-0\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which is to say $f_1=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ and $f_2=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ (here, $f_1,f_2$ are the components of $f$), so try rewriting that instead.

@Thorgott I have fixed the errors. Now the form $-gdx+gdy$ is indeed non-vanishing, so things might work out. Though, I am not sure how am I supposed to integrate $f$ in order to arrive at contradiction?

Note that the integral of a differential $\mathrm d f$ along any closed curve must be zero. Now integrate your form along a circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

I'm afraid this is still not accurate. The codomain of $g$ ought to be $\mathbb{R}$ and not $\mathbb{R}^2$. Nothing else makes sense.

@Thorgott Ohh... you're right, my bad for being sloppy

This is still messed up. The corresponding $1$-form is famously closed, but not exact, as its integral over the unit circle is $2\pi$.  Stokes’s Theorem does not apply. Writing $f$ for a vector field is probably unnecessarily confusing, and omitting its vector structure is even worse.
